# Mobile like home button for a dashboard page

Tags: homepage, dashboard

I am currently designing a dashboard page that shows various graphs and important updates and then there are links to sub pages with more specific information. Is it worthwhile to show a 'Home' button such as in mobile? I feel this is a critical functionality because If the user is lost or want to come back to the main dashboard again, it would be easy to click this prominent 'Home' button or icon. Are there any other better ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the 'home' page serves an important purpose in its own right and is somewhere that the user is likely to want to return to again and again (and it sounds like your dashboard is exactly that) I would absolutely include an explicit and prominent link back to it just for convenience. To look at it another way, there are no significant UX benefits in *not providing* a link back to the dashboard but there is a clear benefit (easier navigation between the detail view and the dashboard overview) if you *do provide* that link.